# Function call not working, but console still allowing input.

Tags: c++

The menu pops up at first which shows a list of items a user can buy. Then the user is asked whether they want to checkout their items or continue shopping. When the user types "no" after being prompted, instead of menu(); being called to bring them back to the menu. Nothing happens. I'm able to type in the console but nothing else shows up.

Here is the code for the question which is in a different function:

```
cout << "Would you like to checkout?" << endl;
cout << "Type 'yes' to continue or 'no' to keep shopping." << endl;
cin >> answer;

if (answer == "yes") {
    checkout(mpadNum, mouseNum, hsetNum, keyboardNum, laptopNum, pcNum);
}
else if (answer == "no") {
    menu(mpadNum, mouseNum, hsetNum, keyboardNum, laptopNum, pcNum);
}
```

Here is the code for part of the menu function if needed:

```
void menu(int mpadNum, int mouseNum, int hsetNum, int keyboardNum, int laptopNum, int pcNum) {

int *mpadQty;
string answer;
string option;

if (file.is_open()) {
    cout << file.rdbuf();
}
cout << " " << endl;
cout << "What would you like to purchase?" << endl;
cout << "Please type your selection." << endl;
cin >> option;

if (option == "mousepad") {
    cout << "How many mousepads would you like?" << endl;
    cin >> mpadNum;
}
mpadQty = new int(mpadNum);
mpadAmnt += *mpadQty;

cout << "Your selection has been added to the cart" << endl;
cout << "Type anything to continue." << endl;
cin >> answer;
cart(mpadNum, mouseNum, hsetNum, keyboardNum, laptopNum, pcNum);
```

}

Comment: Time to dust off your debugger and step through your code to find out why.

Comment: @tadman I honestly don't know what I'm doing wrong. My code looks like it should work like I want it to, but it's not.

Comment: And stepping through with a debugger will help you solve that.

Comment: @user4581301 Sorry. I don't think I quite understand. I'm still new to this. I'm using the debugger. Could you clarify?

Comment: Another thing to node here is using `int` pointers is really bad form and bound to be nothing but trouble. Just use an `int`. Dynamically allocating it offers zero advantage in this case.

Comment: @iluusion What you do is set a breakpoint where you're having a problem, like that `menu` call, and then run your code. Hopefully the debugger will pop on the breakpoint when it's about to call `menu(...)` and you can "step in" to find out more.

Comment: If you don't know how to use that debugger there's surely innumerable tutorials on the subject. The basics take about half an hour to pick up and will save you hours, days, months of time over your career.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a debugging hint. Try printing out the `answer` after your line `cin >> answer`.

```
cout << "answer->" << answer << "<-" << endl;
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. My "yes" answer works. But when I type "no", it takes the answer but doesn't call menu(); I really don't know what I'm doing incorrectly.